# how can we match edittext contact name to listview contact in android

Tags: java, android

sir i need your help for match first character of edit text to match our phonebook listview contact.i want to match edit text name to listvew name and show in edittext .please help me.
i want to implement contact search in android using edittext match contact with listview and dilplay bt one by one acc to search.

```
   private  EditText inputSearch;
     privat ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
String products[]={ };``
  @Override

    contactsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
    contactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    contactsList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   inputSearch=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem,      R.id.product_name, products);
    contactsList.setAdapter(adapter);  
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3{

    ContactsFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: look at api demos content-provider-pick contact example

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Filter to your ListAdapter and use anytime your EditText content is changing.
I have a Filter code that filters a ListView by characters you get in the onFilter, but it is home, hope someone will post an answer till i'll get there,or i will post it when i will get home.

Comment: this better suits in comment section not in answer section

Comment: don't know why can't comment his post.So i'm sorry for this :)
I have a Filter code that filters a ListView by characters you get int onFilter, but it is home, hope someone will post an answer till i'll get there,or i will post it when i will get home.

Comment: its because you need atleast 50 reputations to comment

Comment: and you think you can give me -1 because of this? i guess it is not my fault, because i have to reach reputation somehow

Comment: He can not do that yet

Comment: @Eddy So to earn reputation you need to ask or answer first.Answer section is meant for answers and comment section for comments and question section for questions.Even if do not downvoted this will be removed because its not an answer.

Comment: @javaBeginner why it is not an answer, i guess he is using regular filter, but he needs to implement his own, so i asked to his question, may be not so clear, but he always can ask for a more detailed answer